# Android 11: saving a file to the selected folder

Tags: storage, android-11

In my app I use ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() to let the user select a folder in the device storage and allow access to it.
However, on Android 11, if I try to save a file on the selected folder, I get this exception:
SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord ... requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

On Android 10- everything works.
So, how can I save a file to the selected folder on Android 11?